# Using Batch file to search for a file containing an input then moving it to another directory

Tags: batch-file, find, move

```
@echo OFF

@find /c /i "james" "C:\Users\ersojt\Desktop\Sample\*.eml" > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    move "C:\Users\ersojt\Desktop\Sample\*.eml" "C:\Users\ersojt\Desktop\Sample2"
) else (
    @echo Failure
)

PAUSE
```

I am trying to use a Batch file to search for a specific file containing an input; then moving this file to another directory.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Using this all the .eml files were moved can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo OFF
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=C:\Users\ersojt\Desktop\Sample\*.eml"
    set "target=C:\Users\ersojt\Desktop\Sample2"
    set "searchString=james"

    set "found="
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        findstr /m /i /l /c:"%searchString%" "%source%" 2^>nul 
    ') do (
        if not defined found set "found=1"
        echo move "%%a" "%target%"
    )

    if not defined found (
        echo Failure
    )

    pause
```

This will use a `findstr` command to search for files containing the indicated search string. `/m` switch is used to only retrieve the matching file names.

The `findstr` is executed by a `for /f` command that will retrieve its output and, for each line in the output, execute the code in the `do` clause, with the line stored in the `for` replaceable parameter (`%%a` in this sample).

Move operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct remove the `echo` that prefixes the `move` command.

Comment: i just removed the echo in front of move and it worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: hi can i use findstr to look for files using file properties like author?
i tried using it as 
set "searchString=Author:"james""

Comment: @LemGon, `findstr` search a literal or a regular expression into the file contents. If the searched term can be found, the file name is echoed. But it only check against file contents.

Comment: @MCND I want this script to wait for new files. I'll run this script once and whenever there is new file this script will move again.